# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/students", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call the new action in the admin/students controller and i cannot understand why it always uses the edit action. I have seen other post mentioning the same problem but i can not find a way to solve my own.I tried also to put in the routes a custom member action inside the student resources and then call it from the generated routes but to no avail.

The routes

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :students do
      resources :grades, :lessons, :comments
    end
    resources :teachers, :grades, :lessons, :comments
  end
```

I use the generated route to call the function

```
  <div class="col-md-8"><%= link_to "New Student account", new_admin_student_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>
```

The complete error

```
   Started GET "/admin/students/new" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-08-06 15:48:53 +0000
Processing by Admin::StudentsController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/admin/_nav.html.erb (38.1ms)
  Rendered admin/students/new.html.erb within layouts/application (75.7ms)
Completed 500  in 231ms

ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/students", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
ics.html.erb within rescues/layout (57.6ms)
```

Comment: Can you do 'rake routes' on a terminal and post the result here?

Comment: Can you post the `admin/students/new.html.erb`? I guess the problem is not with link.

Comment: The issue looks to be somewhere in the `new.html.erb` file... something in there (or that's included by it, perhaps `ics.html.erb`?) is trying to render a link. Take a look at where your error occurs in the output.

Comment: You were completely right. I did not expect the problem to come from there. I had navigation bar partial where i put some local variables.       <%= render partial: 'shared/admin/nav', locals: {student: @student} %>

Comment: I think the problem not in your route but in your new.html 
you may having a link that contains an id ,which is nill

Answer (score 0):

Your `Student edit` path should be look like:

```
edit_admin_student_path(@student)
```